# How to log with application insights in a .NET library class?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, azure-application-insights, azure-function-app

I have a C# .NET (4.6.1) Class Library that is being consumed by an Azure function app (V3). I am trying to get that Class Library to use the function app's App Insights for logging, but I'm completely lost on how to even start with setting it up correctly. I'm pretty sure I need the settings saved on the consuming function app, but not sure how to get the class library then to access those settings. Does anyone have any example code or suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: If you connecting to azure application insights then you need only `instrumentation key` which can be read as Environment variable from the class library.

Comment: Normally you just take dependency on ILogger (from Microsoft.Extensions.Logging) and let whoever uses the library to deal with logging configuration...

Comment: Describe more details about your aim? E.g. I need to create a function with dotnet core and it will be triggered by http request and do xx things. And I need to use application insights to log key notes in running process.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a class library, those `ddl`s  are consumed by other applications. Hence, they become a part of other applications.

So, for reading `App Insights instrumentation key` in your class library, you have to use the  following code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("DefaultConnectionString")
```

Using this will fetch setting `DefaultConnectionString` from your consumer App's settings.